# createMaterialTopTabNavigator can't modify tabStyle paddingVertical

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[Two lines up and down are createMaterialTopTabNavigator,I wont to customize the next line, but I can't remove paddingVertical part like the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/224RK.jpg)

```
tabBarOptions={{
          scrollEnabled: true,
          style: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          },
          tabStyle: {
            width: 'auto',
            margin: theme.sizes.radius,
            padding: 0, //only horizontal works,how to modify vertical padding ?
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          },
          labelStyle: {
            margin: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
          activeTintColor: theme.colors.default,
          renderIndicator: () => null,
        }}
```

Comment: tabStyle: {minHeight: null} works

Answer (score 0):

Try just style under tabBarOptions

```
tabBarOptions={{
    labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
    tabStyle: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    style: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' },
}}
```

Detail here [tabnavigator-extra-padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814791/tabnavigator-extra-padding)

Comment: Thank you, but I found the solution, source code has minHeight:48,so only set tabStyle: {minHeight: null} works.